# How do I CSS layer on top of ASP.NET Image?

Tags: asp.net, css

At the top of my screen, I have an ASP.NET Hyperlink with an image representing the company and the application. I want to use CSS layers to place text or some control displaying text on top of the hyperlink/image at bottom right hand corner representing the productEdition.

I can't post the ASP.NET Hyperlink markup because it causes error but it has an ImageUrl. Oh, it's in a panel. See below:

```
<asp:panel ID="toppanel" CssClass='wrapper' runat="server">
<!--Top Menu-->           
<asp:panel id="menupanel" runat="server" CssClass="menusubwrapper">
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HeaderLink" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Header.gif" NavigateURl="~/Default.aspx" ToolTip="Home Page">   
    </asp:HyperLink>
</asp:panel>
```

Using the techniques in some of the answers, I have this working - the text is on top of the picture but it's all the way to the left. I need it to be all the way to the right.

```
   <asp:panel ID="toppanel" CssClass='wrapper' runat="server">
        <!--Top Menu-->           
        <asp:panel id="menupanel" runat="server" CssClass="menusubwrapper">

         <div id="Header" style="position: relative; z-index: 1">
          <%--div style="position:absolute;z-index:1">--%>
              <asp:HyperLink ID="HeaderLink" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Header.gif" 
              NavigateURl="~/Default.aspx" ToolTip="Home Page">   
              </asp:HyperLink>

               <div style="position:absolute;top:60px; right:400px; width:600px; height:100px; z-index:2;font-size:200%">
                   <b>Testing...</b>
               </div>
         <%--</div>--%>
 </div>`
```

Comment: Show us how you are coding it, or we won't be able to help you out.

Comment: No div but <asp:HyperLink ID="HeaderLink" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Header.gif" 
            NavigateURl="~/Default.aspx" ToolTip="Home Page">
            </asp:HyperLink>

Comment: Please edit your question with that information, then.

Comment: I can't. It won't let me me put the HTML there even with a code block!!

Comment: I just tested and you can post html in a code block. Also, since you've put your code there, I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a div to overlap the image with the Edition in it. You can read about overlapping elements here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Hope this helps and Good Luck!

Comment: I looked and I can do a Z-Index of -1 but how do I ensure it gets placed on top of the image in the Hyperlink control?

Comment: Put the Hyperlink control in a div and then use the Z-Index to control which element is overlapping. I typically set borders on my divs until they are positioned correctly. It makes it a lot easier to understand what is taking place. For example, in one div put border:2px solid red; and the other put border:2px solid black; You can use this until they are positioned and then remove the border.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a DIV wrapping around the linked image as well as around the text (also within a DIV). Give the wrapping DIV a style "position:relative" and give the text DIV absolute positioning. Or, instead of using absolute positioning, you could float it right or left, center it, using margins, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tutorials for you:

http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/lesson15.php

OR

http://www.xul.fr/en/css/text-over-image.php

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution:

```
<div id="Header" style="position: relative; z-index: 1">

                <asp:HyperLink ID="HeaderLink" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Header.gif" 
                               NavigateURl="~/Default.aspx" ToolTip="Home Page"/>   

                <div style="position:absolute;top:60px; left:800px; width:600px; height:100px; z-index:2;font-size:200%">
                    <%--<b>Testing...</b>--%>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                </div>

            </div>
```